# All SD card mounts read-only after mounting locked card

Tags: drivers, sd-card

I'm having a project with the SD card reader (likely driver) for my Dell machine running 18.04.

If I ever insert a SD card in the "locked" position, any other SD card can not be written to regardless of the physical potion of the switch, until the next re-boot.

One odd thing, is if the switch on the card is unlocked, it says "Operation not permitted", but if it's locked it says "Read-only file system" (as it should).

How I'm testing:

umount the FS if it's auto mounted. Then doing a simple "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1" to delete the MBR. This gives the error. So it's not a wrong/weird file system issue.

Once the SD reader has mounted a read-only card, you can never write to another card again until a reboot. reading is fine.

Booting to windows w/o touching the card, and writing is fine (assuming the card is in the unlocked position).

So maybe a driver and/or automount bug?

Any ideas on how to reset it w/ out having to reboot?

lshw just says the device is a "Mass storage device" and "Flash card Reader/Writer". The vendor is "Generic"